# Relating to permissions

Tags: 12.04

I am unable to create a folder in "www" folder  for php in ubuntu 12.04 file system directory . could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: What happens when you try to create the folder?

Comment: did you add the user you are doing this with to the group apache  uses? if not... do not start messing with permissions... add the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what processes will need to be doing this and set the appropriate owner/group permissions. For instance with drupal installation you have to set up certain directories as giving the www-data group write permission.

Basic unix commands for doing these things:

chmod nnn [file or directory]
or
chmod -R nnn directory/  (if you want a recursive change)

where "nnn" is the numeric value of the user/group/world permissions (google these values, but 777 means read/write/execute

chown : [file or directory]
changes the ownership